# SQL showing an error when creating table with columns that have the data type longtext

Tags: mysql, sql

So im makign a framework that has the option to cache and store files, now one of the cache sources is xe_templates for theme templates, my query looks like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    name LONGTEXT(4294967295),
    lastedit LONGTEXT(4294967295),
    data LONGTEXT(4294967295),
    type LONGTEXT(4294967295),
    lastEdit LONGTEXT(4294967295)
);
```

the error I get is this

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(4294967295),
    lastedit LONGTEXT(4294967295),
    data LONGTEXT(42949672...' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VARCHAR()` takes a length, but the text types do not.  So just use:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    name LONGTEXT,
    lastedit LONGTEXT,
    data LONGTEXT,
    type LONGTEXT,
    lastEdit2 LONGTEXT
);
```

That said, `LONGTEXT` should be used sparingly.  I have trouble imagining a name that is going to be measured in the Mbytes or Gbytes.

I changed the name of the last column to `lastEdit2` because two columns cannot have the same name in a table.

Comment: you changed the last field to `lastEdit2`, please explain it (why) in your answer.

Comment: you can't have two columns with the same name besides this will nbe confusing

Comment: @nbk i think my request was simple. When you write an answer you explain your changes. One of which is the change of the name of the last column. I thought it would be helpful to refer that column names are not case sensitive. That is all.

Comment: @Xfaon https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html#:~:text=Partition%2C%20subpartition%2C%20column%2C%20index,logfile%20groups%20are%20case%2Dsensitive.